# Use elasticsearch to detect terms, so I can assign those terms to categories and visualize the documents by category

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a huge amount of documents with the following (relevant) schema:

```
{
  ...
  "Description": "word1 word2 ... wordN",
  ...
}
```

I want to use Elasticsearch to somehow extract for me the most repeating words (or phrases) from `Description`, among all documents. Something like:

- word1: 12
- word2: 9
- word4 word5: 5 <-- note this is a whole phrase
- word4: 3
- ...

I guess this should be done with [term vector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html).

Now, I want to maintain a tree structure of 'categories', as in index, like:

- Root

  - Child 1

    - Child 1.1
  - Child 2

    - Child 2.1
    - Child 2.2

And I want to assign a detected term to a leaf in the category tree. e.g.

- Root

  - Category 1 (word1)

    - Child 1.1 (word2, word4)
  - Category 2

    - Category 2.1 (word4 word5)
    - Category 2.2 (wordN)

That assignment would be a 'manual' (conscious) operation from my side, but I need ES to at least provide me the common phrases/words it has detected.

Then when I search for my documents, I want Elasticsearch to somehow correlate the document to a leaf in my tree structure (as a property).

e.g.:

```
{
  ...
  "Description": "word4 word5 word6",
  "Category": "Category 2.1" <-- by elasticsearch, based on 'word4 word5' in the Description
  ...
}
```

I want to use all this, so I can visualize my documents in Kibana by 'category'.

I am very new to ES and Kibana, how would I generally approach this?

Comment: For the amount of processing you need done prior to indexing the content, I would question if this is solely a job for Elastic. Have you considered running your items through a keyword extractor (eg. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/text-analytics/ or something similar) ? This may be an easier task if you run through logstash scripts that enrich your data before indexing.

Comment: @MikeMichaels this is great advice, I've just tried it and seems like it would work for my initial set. However, data will keep streaming into my solution. I don't want to run the entire (updated) set through the keyword extractor every time. I would expect that when ES indexes a new document, it would update my keywords/phrases.

Comment: Also, that Azure service is advertised as cognitive, which is not exactly my case. I haven't specified but the 'description' of my documents is more or less variations of different often repeating strings.

Comment: Ahhh, so you will have to ingest the entire set more than once? There are many other options for keyword extraction. Elastic can do much of this for you. It seems like your requirements dictate you would need to run some processing against your document, apply the results of that back to the document itself, and then index it. Whenever I've needed to accomplish something like that, I've found it easier to do it somewhere in an application prior to indexing. Ingestion pipelines may make this possible for you. https://www.elastic.co/blog/new-way-to-ingest-part-1